# How to attach Database after uploading website to server using Core FTP Le

Tags: php, database, ftp, web

I first established my website using

```
 localhost server
```

after establishing it, i found

```
Core FTP LE software
```

for uploading website, i upload website and then i load website on browser i found database is not working but except database related code, the whole website loaded properly. I've searched a lot about how to use

```
Core FTP LE software
```

to attach database but i found nothing, Please guys help me.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is thus off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It may be a better fit on our sister site [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload database via FTP. You need to import it via MySQL CLI or PHPMyAdmin and do the connections with your PHP application.
Maybe if you can share more details about your server setup, we can assist you more.